# Change the data format from varchar to date

Tags: mysql

I want to change the data format from one column (order_date) of my table (table1) (to do a time selection) -> the format in the moment is varchar and the structure of the entries is like `13.04.2009 07:35:40`I tried this already but it´s not working:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY order_date Datetime;
```

What´s wrong?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8189128/6107715 may this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `ALTER` statement but can convert that to `datetime` while fetching the data like

```
select cast(order_date as datetime) as new_date
from table1;
```

But you should never store datetime data as string or `varchar`. It should be stored in `datetime` datatype column only. Now, since you already have data in that column; `ALTER` looks bit misleading.

You can take a backup of your current data. Create a intermediary table with same structure having `order_date datetime`. Then perform a `insert into .. select from` like below. Then probably rename that table to original table (before that drop the existing table);

```
insert into intermediary_table
select col1,col2, cast(order_date as datetime), col3
from table1;
```

Comment: it´s not working probably - gives out this warning:  64 warning(s):
 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '13.11.2012 04:00:17'
 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '13.11.2012 04:00:17'
 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '29.11.2012 05:21:23'
...
 Records: 862027  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 862027 14.758 sec

Comment: Those are warnings and not error. did you get any records fetched?

Comment: Also, try using `CONVERT()` function as well which accepts date format.

Comment: From what I see your varchar date is a german format. But the datetime format is english. You need to convert them.

Comment: the orderdate is NULL now everywhere

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner, You need to provide more information. post your table structure, sample data

Comment: I found the solution: my mistake :/

Answer (score 0):

you can update the table as :

```
UPDATE `table1`
SET `order_date` = str_to_date( `order_date`, '%d-%m-%Y' );
```

Comment: What if the table has 1M rows? will go on performing an update to all rows? is that you are suggesting?

Comment: @Rahul I was just giving a try to solve his query. Data handling is a different part and off-curse I wont suggest this solution for huge data.

Answer (score 0):

The str_to_date function needs to be told the order on which the data and time elements appear and the separators
in this case

```
set @dt = '13.04.2009 07:35:40';

select @dt ,STR_TO_DATE(@dt,'%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') 
from dual;
```

Results in

```
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| @dt                 | STR_TO_DATE(@dt,'%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 13.04.2009 07:35:40 | 2009-04-13 07:35:40                  |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Note this is only a part solution @Rahuls approach to "fixing" the table looks sound and if it works for you should mark his answer as correct.